# facing issues while running react js script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i downloaded the create-react-app script and made some changes on it like added a button and state n all but when I run my code through VS Code with the help of live server I'm unable to see the output on my browser. However, if I did the same using a command line I,m able to see my desired output .
So where am I wrong here ? do I need to run my code through cmd all the time ? or what?

here's my code of the component named App.js :

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [data,setState] = useState(0)

  function updateData(){
    setState(data+1)
  }
  return (
  <div className= "App">
    <p>{data}</p>
  
  <buton onClick = {updateData}>ddsj</buton></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please add your views or tell me  what else should I add to for you to understand what i'm trying to ask.

Comment: if you do `npm start` in the terminal in your root directory it will start the React development server. it's like live server but for React, basically.

Comment: yes thats what I'm asking , should I do npm start everytime I want to run my script?

Comment: like for the first time? cant I use live server directly instead ? what the prob here ? can you please tell

Comment: no, just do `npm start`. It's just like live server. every time you make changes, the server will restart for you!

Comment: okay thanks man , got it

Answer (score 0):

You must type `npm start` each time you want to run the application for the first time.